# Progress bar similar to bar-code scanner on photo taken image

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to do scanner image similar to bar-code scanner which needs to be displayed on photo taken from camera image.This i am trying it on ionic app for both android/ios

I am trying to have do scanner similar in below image which comes in red color:
[image]

Which shows user that its scanning the image taken from camera.

Could you please help me out with some inputs will be really helpful.Thanks.

Comment: any solutions or suggestions people ? stuck with this thing from couple of days.

Answer (score 0):

you have to find this file in your library and edit viewfinder_border.

https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner/blob/master/core/src/main/res/values/colors.xml

Comment: I wanted this effect not for bar scanner app but for other app which takes photo from camera.Once after taking photo on top of the image i need to show the bar-code scanner type bar animation on my image captured.